# why is my pip installing tool not working anymore with python version 3.7

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` on a project I get this error message:

> pip._vendor.pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.2.2
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
> Requirement.parse('pip==20.1.1'))

Why is that happening? I am completely blocked on working on new projects.

My python version is 3.7.8 and I am working on a MAC.

Has this something to do with homebrew python version is now 3.8 what is also installed on my machine.

Comment: Did you tried to upgrade pip? `pip install -U pip`

Comment: I get this ```Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.2.2)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try upgrading your pip version.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

2. If this does pesist, consider using python virtual environments ([venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html))

Comment: Why would a virtual environment help here?

Comment: If the outdated pip version was a requirement for some other module

Comment: the install command has not worked but I used venv then it started working

Answer (score 3):

It looks like pip is mentioned in the `requirements.txt` file, requiring a specific version of pip. Installation should work when you remove the line which specifies the pip version from `requirements.txt`.

`requirements.txt` should mention the packages you need for your project, not the tool which you need to install those requirements. That's kind of self-referencing.